# Как обрабатывать события в джанго?

Tags: django, веб-программирование, django-rest-framework

Допустим, на моем сайте есть видео и я хочу присваивать ему статус просмотренно в бд, если пользователь посмотрел больше чем 50%, как мне реализовать это ?
Меня немного ввело в тупик эта задачка, ведь при запуске и выключении видео никакие запросы не посылаются, я ведь прав?
Возможно ли это?

Comment: Джаваскриптом отслеживать текущую позицию видео (и джанго тут уже ни при чём)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно, но это делается полностью на стороне клиента, и для этого в Javascript у элемента `<video>` есть событие `timeupdate` чтобы следить за прогрессом и вот внизу предоставил пример этой реализации:

```js
const loadVideo = document.querySelector("button");
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const viewedBlock = document.querySelector("#viewed");

let source = null;
let viewed = false; // Этот флаг можем получать с бакенда

viewedBlock.textContent = viewed;

function handleTimeupdate(event) {
  const currentTime = video.currentTime;
  const duration = video.duration;

  // Вычисляем процент просмотра видео
  const percentageViewed = (currentTime / duration) * 100;

  // Если процент больше 50% и видео ещё не было отмечено как просмотренное, выполняем действия, например отправляем запрос на сервер
  if (percentageViewed >= 50 && !viewed) {
    // Отправляем запрос на сервер для отметки видео как просмотренного
    viewed = true;
    viewedBlock.textContent = viewed;
  }
}

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeupdate);

loadVideo.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (source) {
    document.location.reload();
  } else {
    loadVideo.textContent = "Сбросить";
    viewed = false;
    source = document.createElement("source");
    source.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/rabbit320.mp4",
    );
    source.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");

    video.appendChild(source);
  }
});
```

```css
video {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <button type="button">Загрузить видео</button>
    <video controls width="250"></video>
  </div>
  <div class="viewed">Просмотрено: <span id="viewed"></span></div>
</div>
```